# Property of divisibility of numbers

Tags: number-theory

How to prove that if $d=GCD(ac,b)$ and $GCD(a,b)=1$ then $d|c$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\gcd(d,a)=l$ then ($l|d\Rightarrow l|b$) & $l|a$ so $l|\gcd(a,b)=1$), thus $l=1$ 
Now we use Euclid's lemma for $d|ac$ and get desired result.

Comment: How can we conclude $l|d\rightarrow l|a$ ? We only know $l|ac$.

Comment: @Peter $\color{red}{gcd(d,a)=l}$ so $l|d$ & $l|a$.

Comment: OK, did not consider that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ (ac,b)\mid ac,bc \, \Rightarrow (ac,b)\mid(ac,bc)=(a,b)c = c$